# Is there any way to make this SQL code with Nested Case statements cleaner?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I do slightly different things based on one variable that can be 10 different options.

```
 (
        CaCartons
        + 
        case when PgFeet is null or PgWeight is null then 0 else
            COALESCE(

                case when CLIENTNAME ='01' then
                    case
                        when PgWeight < @CartonMaxWeight and PgFeet < @CartonMaxVolume01
                            then 1
                        when PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight >= PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume01
                            then PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight
                        else
                            PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume01
                    end
                else null end,

                case when CLIENTNAME ='02' then
                    case
                        when PgWeight < @CartonMaxWeight and PgFeet < @CartonMaxVolume02
                            then 1
                        when PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight >= PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume02
                            then PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight
                        else
                            PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume02
                    end
                else null end,

                case when CLIENTNAME ='03' then
                    case
                        when PgWeight < @CartonMaxWeight and PgFeet < @CartonMaxVolume03
                            then 1
                        when PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight >= PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume03
                            then PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight
                        else
                            PgFeet / @CartonMaxVolume03
                    end
                else null end
            )
        end
    ) TotalCartons
```

This goes on for 10 more CLIENTNAMES

Is there any way to make this code cleaner and more easy to read?

Comment: it's a `CASE` **expression**; there are no `Case` statements in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I would put much more logic in the `FROM` clause.  I think this is the logic you want:

```
select . . .,
       (CaCartons +
        (case when PgFeet is null or PgWeight is null then 0 
              when PgWeight < @CartonMaxWeight and PgFeet < v.CartonMaxVolume01
              then 1
              when PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight >= PgFeet / v.CartonMaxVolume01
              then PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight
              else PgFeet / v.CartonMaxVolume01
         end)
        )
from t left join
     (values ('client01', @CartonMaxVolume01),
             ('client02', @CartonMaxVolume02),
             . . .
     ) v(client, CartonMaxVolume)
     on t.client = v.client
```

Answer (score 0):

To refactor and reuse an expression in multiple places in a query, you can hoist it into a Common Table Expression, and SELECT from that.  eg:

```
with q as
(
   select *, 
   case when CLIENTNAME ='01' then @CartonMaxVolume01
        when CLIENTNAME ='02' then @CartonMaxVolume02
        when CLIENTNAME ='03' then @CartonMaxVolume03
        else null end ClientCartonMaxVolume
   from ...
)
select 
        CaCartons
        + 
        case when PgFeet is null or PgWeight is null then 0 
             when PgWeight < @CartonMaxWeight and PgFeet < ClientCartonMaxVolume then 1
             when PgWeight / @CartonMaxWeight >= PgFeet / ClientCartonMaxVolume
             else  PgFeet / ClientCartonMaxVolume end  as TotalCartons
from q;
```